# Screenshot code creating fuzzy screenshots

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, image, bitmap

I have been using image recgonition in my program, and kept thinking it was a a problem with the actual image recognition code in my application. After looking into it deeper and deeper I realized that the code I use to create the screenshots, both fullscreen and partial rectangles of the screen is creating fuzzy images. The images are blurry and coming out pixelated.

I do not usually save the images I just use the bitmaps in the memory for the imagerecognition to check against. Although after saving these screenshots in multiple formats I can see the issue.

Here is the code I use to generate the screenshots.  The first function creates a full screenshot the second one creates one from coordinates on the screen.

```
   Public Shared Function GetScreen() As Bitmap
    Dim screenSize As Size = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)
        g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screenSize)
        Return screenGrab
    End Using
End Function

  Public Shared Function 
    GetScreenXY(TopLeft As Point, BottomRight As Point) As Bitmap
    Dim w As Integer = BottomRight.X - TopLeft.X
    Dim h As Integer = BottomRight.Y - TopLeft.Y
    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(w, h)   'width and height of the rectangle you want to grab
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)
        g.CopyFromScreen(TopLeft, New Point(0, 0), screenGrab.Size)
        Return screenGrab
    End Using
End Function
```

I also have a screenshot tool in my application that I recently added. It has a form that can be resized and it takes a screenshot and can save it. These come out fuzzy as well. It uses the second function.

```
        Visible = False
        Dim screenShot As Bitmap = ImageFinder.GetScreenXY(New Point(Left, Top), New Point(Right, Bottom))
        Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog
        sfd.Filter = "Jpeg image (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Bitmap image (*.bmp)|*.bmp| PNG image (*.png)|*.png"
        sfd.Title = "Save image"
        If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            If sfd.FileName <> String.Empty Then
                'Set to Jpeg by default.
                Dim MyImageFormat As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg
                If sfd.FileName.ToString.ToUpper.EndsWith("JPG") Then
                    MyImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg
                ElseIf sfd.FileName.ToString.ToUpper.EndsWith("BMP") Then
                    MyImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp
                ElseIf sfd.FileName.ToString.ToUpper.EndsWith("PNG") Then
                    MyImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png
                End If
                screenShot.Save(sfd.FileName, MyImageFormat)
```

Comment: Do all of the file formats look fuzzy or just the jpg?

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine... hmm.  Maybe upload an example, so we can see exactly what you mean by "fuzzy"?

Comment: I have only been saving as png and BMP. In the image saving code on the bottom is there anyway to save the images as high quality? If I take a screenshot in my application and save and and take a print screen and paste it into paint and save it in the same format, the printscreen version is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is MY way of taking screenshots and it takes them very nicely and I thought I would share it with you.

```
    'Declare my constants here for screenshots'
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT As Short = &H2CS

'Create my function to take the picture of the screen'
Public Function SaveScreen(ByVal theFile As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim data As IDataObject
        data = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
        Dim bmap As Bitmap
        If data.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then
            bmap = CType(data.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), Bitmap)
            Me.picScreen.Image = bmap
            Me.picScreen.Image.Save(theFile, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If
    Catch s As Exception
    End Try
End Function
```

Now let's save this picture...

```
    Private Sub btnSavePic_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSavePic.Click
    Try

            Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Snapshot, 0, 0, 0)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200) ' To have time to catch the clipboard
            SaveScreen("YOURFILELOCATION" & Format(Now, "MM-dd-yyyy ") & " " & Format(TimeOfDay, "hhmmss") & ".bmp")

    Catch w As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Give it a shot, I use this for reporting back my screen to me when I am away...